# KDB adding column index to a table

Tags: kdb

I have a table that has meta of all tables in a partitioned database. What is the best way of adding a column with index of each column for that table to this one?

```
q)t1
tables   cols
--------------
tab1     col1
tab1     col2
tab1     col3
tab2     col1
tab2     col2
tab2     col3

Expected output

q)t1
tables   cols  indexOfCol
-------------------------
tab1     col1   0
tab1     col2   1
tab1     col3   2
tab2     col1   0
tab2     col2   1
tab2     col3   2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include code to create example tables if you can:

```
q)t:([] tab:`t1`t1`t2`t3`t3`t3;cls:`c1`c2`c1`c1`c2`c3)
```

Use `til count i by`:

- https://code.kx.com/q/ref/select/#by-phrase
- https://code.kx.com/q/ref/til/
- https://code.kx.com/q/basics/qsql/#virtual-column-i

```
q)t
tab cls
--------
t1   c1
t1   c2
t2   c1
t3   c1
t3   c2
t3   c3
q)update indexOfCol:til count i by tab from t
tab cls indexOfCol
------------------
t1  c1  0
t1  c2  1
t2  c1  0
t3  c1  0
t3  c2  1
t3  c3  2
```

Do not use `tables` or `cols` as column names. They are function names which will cause you problems:

- https://code.kx.com/q/ref/tables/
- https://code.kx.com/q/ref/cols/